# Developing a Java web service using Jersey(JAX-RS), mySQL and Eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, web-services, jakarta-ee, jersey

I have successfully created Web Services from MySQL Database using [Netbeans tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html). However, I would like to develop similar web services using Eclipse IDE. Why Eclipse IDE? There are two reasons for that:

1) This is because i am using Tomcat 7.0 and JEE6. Unfortunately, NetBeans 7.0.1 implements Facade design pattern while using their “Create Web services from Database …” Wizard and it does not have a plugin for Tomcat 7 and EE6.

2) The NetBeans Wizard is helpful but does not help me understand details about using JDBC bridge, managing connections to MySQL DB and creating services to access the DB. Additionally, i want to add authorization for my services so that only registered users will be able to access my web services.

Comment: Just a personal opinion: in general, building one-to-one mappings from DB table to service using only tools is a bad idea. Do you need to publish each individual table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very [clear tutorial](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#getting-started) for building JAX-RS services in the Jersey user guide.

Comment: I went through that tutorial but i need one that shows how i can build Web services from Database and that too using Tomcat 7 and Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial that contains Restful web services using java and mysql in eclipse. It might be what you were looking for though it is a very simple tutorial. Check it out.
http://www.techpages.org/webservice/simple-restful-web-services-using-java-and-mysql-example/2009/